What is the rationale for specifying dynamic width and precision _after_ the argument in str.format?
In C programming language dynamic field width and precision is specified before the argument.
printf("%.*s", 2, "ABCDEF")

Yet when str.format was introduced in Python3.0 in 2008 the dynamic field width and precision is specified after the argument.
"{:.{}}".format("ABCDEF", 2)

Why is that? I find specifying dynamic field width after the argument very confusing. Is there a specific technical reason for it, or is it a preference of the author?
(The origin of my question is, C++ {fmt} also wants dynamic field width and precision after the argument, yet C++ is statically typed langauge. My guess is {fmt} blindly followed python specification. As C++ is not dynamically typed like Python, I do not think it was a correct decision, so I decided to ask the community about clarification of the original decision in Python.)
@edit Just mentioning, I wrote to the author of PEP 3101 and received a response that it was 17 years ago, and he does not remember and suggested to go through mailing Python list around 2007.

So, this is simply a consequence of the way that fields with no names are assigned to the positional arguments. Which is "in order" in the simplest, unnested case. A simple example:
"{}{}".format(1, 2)

is equivalent to:
"{0}{1}".format(1, 2)

And apparently, nested fields inside another fields format specifier work in an "outside-in" order.
So:
"{:.{}}"

Is equivalent to:
"{0:.{1}}"

I cannot find where this is actually specified in the docs, although it's quite late where I am currently, so I could be just missing it.
Of course, you could not rely on unnamed blank fields, so this could work for you:
"{1:.{0}}".format(2, "ABCDEF")

Or alternatively, use keyword arguments:
"{val:.{width}}".format(width=2, val="ABCDEF")


I think this is true. Reading the mailing list https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-December/710588.html , https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.python/c/U3FsQTa-Rzs  I got to the introduction of "auto numbering fields" in https://bugs.python.org/issue5237 . The fields are just auto-numbered, so the first { is number field 0, the second { is field 1 and so on, so {0:{1}} is the same as {:{}}. While I "see" that now, I still find it confusing, as porting requires rewritting printf("%.*f", w, f) into format("{.{}}", f, w);.

Also moving from % to {} is a "huge can of worms" https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-September/092399.html

I don't think this is really comparable .. in Python, the inner {} is simply after the first, so it discovers its argument as the next argument to the string .format() method
note that the ordering can be reversed if the field(s) are indexed or named
>>> "{1:.{0}}".format(2, "ABCDEF")
'AB'
>>> "{s:.{}}".format(2, s="ABCDEF")
'AB'

additional fields are ignored
>>> "{:.{}}".format("ABCDEF", 2, 3, 4)
'AB'

and also that it will accept a string before the final evaluation!
>>> "{:.{}}".format("ABCDEF", "2")
'AB'


I do not understand "the inner {} is after the first". It's not, the inner is before the first. You have to know precision and width before printing the field. What I believe your answer is saying, is that the reason is technical - it is easier in python source code to parse the format string specification by taking the argument upon encountering the { character. I am searching for an exact answer, if possible. Is this true?

I do not see that reading https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b941e57c71d7d0ab983d81a169f892662cfe446/Objects/stringlib/unicode_format.h#L833 - inner format specification is expanded before render_field the actual field is rendered. We could just move fieldobj = get_field_object( after computing format spec, and precision would be taken before the argument (as I understand the source code).

hmm.. .format() isn't looking for any particular N-part field members, but for each field's name in its arguments, which it takes to be 0, 1, etc. if not expressly provided

for example, you can say "{1} {1} {1} {s} {s}".format("A", "B", s="C"), which is effectively filling from the dict {0: "A", 1: "B", "s": "C"}

Huh. I forgot str.format() existed! I expect you'll see one of these forms instead overwhelmingly more often now:
>> a = "ABCDEF"
>>> format(a, '.2')
'AB'
>>> f'{a:.2}'
'AB'

As to why the object comes first, that's because formatting knowledge is implemented by the objects being formatted in Python. "Object first" is like "self" in a class method.
That doesn't make sense in C, where, unless your compiler works hard to protect you, the codes in a format string may be handed any values (in the argument list) whatsoever, even if they make no sense (e.g., passing a struct argument to a "%d" specifier). "%d" itself has no way to know it's being asked to do a senseless thing, and even segfaults may result. That can't happen in Python. In an analogous case, the "struct object" would be passed the "%d" specifier, and raise a well-behaved "huh? that makes no sense to me" ValueError.
Example:
>>> "ABCD".__format__(".2") # objects use dunder method to format
'AB'
>>> "ABCD".__format__("d") # and reject codes they don't know about
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'


You do not use str.format()? formatting knowledge is implemented by the objects being formatted in Python I like that reasoning. Do you know if there is any reference, in the context of formatting string, to back it up?

str.format() is useless to me. I use the alternatives I showed. BTW, see the example I added in an edit at the end. The internal __format__ protocol was introduced in PEP 3101. https://peps.python.org/pep-3101/ That PEP also introduced the quite distinct str.format() method, which IMO should be deprecated. "f" strings were always "the right way" to do this, but took decades to be discovered ;-)

I'd really expect a user to slice [:2] in this particular scenario too!
